# onkeypress textbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<input type="text" ID="txtMy" name="txtMy" onkeypress="initialize();"/>
```

And in my .js file I have:

```
initialize()
{
    var x = $("#txtMy").val();
}
```

But, if I have '2' in my textbox, and then I enter 4, the value of x is still 2. How to resolve this?

Comment: Using inline attributes to attach event handlers is bad practice. There's really no excuse for doing it if you're using a framework such as jQuery, since it makes the whole process of binding them so easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keyup`

Here is how you do that in the [unobtrusive way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtMy" />
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){
  $("#txtMy").keyup(function (event) {
    alert($(this).val())
  });
});
```

Working Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/VmELF/4/

If you want to bind the functionality to a text box which is being injected to the DOM after the dom load( possible by an Ajax call etc...), you may use jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on("keyup","#txtSearchKey",function (event) {
    alert($(this).val())
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your spelling of initialize in the onkeypress does not match the declaration (`inititalize`).

Answer (score 1):

`keydown` and `keypress` events both execute BEFORE the entered key has actually appeared in the text box. If you want to get the new value of the input after the key has appeared, use the `keyup` event instead.

```
<input type="text" ID="txtMy" name="txtMy" onkeyup="initialize();"/>

initialize()
{
    var x = $("#txtMy").val();
}
```

You should consider binding your event handlers in javascript using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), since you're using the library anyways. Keeping your logic (javascript) seperated from your view (html) is a good habit to get in to.

Answer (score 0):

instead of markup event handler you can use jquery:

```
var x;

$("#txtMy").on("keyup", function(){
     x = $(this).val();
     alert(x);
})
```

Comment: Deleted my previous comment since you've edited the question and made it irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Use the `keyup` event. `keypress` is firing before the character is recorded.
2. Your initialize() function is misspelled in your HTML snippet.

See the working jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/8XTLW/1/